# Ionic 3: How to get keydown/keypress events on external keyboard at any time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic3

So, i have a barcode scanner, connected by microsub (otg), and it's recognized as an external keyboard. What i need to do is to catch any keydown or keypress event at any time (not just on focus on input). Also, it would be great to know if the evvent was fired by the virtual keyboard or the physical one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

hi jonyjm Bellow is the scanner example with cdn link

1 Scann with focus scannerInput text box or type here 
  That will display in top text box for example

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
   
</head>

<body>
    <input id="userInput" type="text" autofocus />


    <br>

    <div class="test">


        <input id="scannerInput" type="text" value="barcodescan" autofocus />
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/scannerdetection/1.2.0/jquery.scannerdetection.compatibility.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/scannerdetection/1.2.0/jquery.scannerdetection.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).scannerDetection({

                //https://github.com/kabachello/jQuery-Scanner-Detection

                timeBeforeScanTest: 200, // wait for the next character for upto 200ms
                avgTimeByChar: 40, // it's not a barcode if a character takes longer than 100ms
                preventDefault: true,

                endChar: [13],
                onComplete: function (barcode, qty) {
                    validScan = true;


                    $('#scannerInput').val(barcode);

                } // main callback function ,
                ,
                onError: function (string, qty) {

                    $('#userInput').val($('#userInput').val() + string);


                }


            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm not using jquery, since is an ionic/angular project.

Comment: just use jquery for data capture then take it by angular

Comment: using jquery is out of the scope of this project, i'm looking for a ionic native solution

Comment: hi you are correct if you need then can access inside the scope by              var scannerdata = angular.element(document.querySelector('#userInput'));